# Why PPP cares about network layer?

Tags: layer2, osi, layer3, ppp

Why PPP have protocol field? Isn't whole purpose of partitioning communication system to have simple isolated subsystems?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

PPP is an encapsulating protocol for transporting various network-layer protocols. The design of PPP puts it in both OSI layer-2 and layer-3. The OSI model is theoretical (what happens in the real world can be very different), and some protocols operate in multiple layers. Because of its design, PPP needs to know something about the network-layer protocol which it is transporting:

> PPP also established a standard for assigning and managing IP
>   addresses, asynchronous and bit-oriented synchronous encapsulation,
>   network protocol multiplexing, link configuration, link quality
>   testing, error detection, and option negotiation for added networking
>   capabilities.

One of the three parts to PPP is the Network Control Protocol. PPP allows different NCPs to be used, depending on which network-layer protocol needs to be encapsulated and transported.

Cisco has a document which explains more about PPP: [Point-to-Point Protocol](http://docwiki.cisco.com/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol)